# Absolute and Flexbox in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I would like to put a white bar which would take all of the width at the bottom of the screen. To do so I thought about using `absolute` positioning with the inherited `flexbox` parameters.

With the following code it renders something like [this](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/494574Capturedcran20150409164910.png).

Here is my code :

```
var NavigationBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
    <View style={navigationBarStyles.navigationBar}>
      //Icon 1, Icon 2...
    </View>
    );
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <View style={mainStyles.container}>
          <NavigationBar />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var mainStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#456783',
  }
});

var navigationBarStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  navigationBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    height: 30,
    position: 'absolute', 
    flexDirection: 'row',
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
});
```

I'm new to styling in CSS and not all the properties are available in React-Native. So any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Ok, solved my problem, if anyone is passing by here is the answer:

Just had to add `left: 0,` and `top: 0,` to the styles, and yes, I'm tired.

```
position: 'absolute',
left:     0,
top:      0,
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that. And it seems likewise for height - instead of `height:100%`, do `top:0, bottom:0`.

Comment: but if you want put the bar in the bottom, and full width, you should add `left:0, right:0`, and should not add `top:0`, if you set `top:0` and `bottom:0`, it will display full screen.

Comment: How can I center? For example I want to show a spinner on top of my component and I want the spinner to be absolute and centered?

Comment: For filling all the space vertically with an absolute positioned child adding ``top:0`` and ``bottom:0`` worked as a replacement for ``height:100%" take to @Premasagar

Comment: Jus add `left`, `top`, `right` and `botton` to 0 and works perfect.

Comment: Unbelievable how Stackoverflow puts this answer at the bottom of the page. I am betting the only reason an exact copy of this (correct) answer has any votes is because SO renders it above this one. SO, WTF?!?!?

Comment: but it does not work inside a `FlatList` component. Probably `FlatList` changes the `absolute` position to scroll down the element and this causes issues **only on android**. The following issue could be related https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18616

Answer (score 73):

The first step would be to add

```
position: 'absolute',
```

then if you want the element full width, add

```
left: 0,
right: 0,
```

then, if you want to put the element in the bottom, add

```
bottom: 0,
// don't need set top: 0
```

if you want to position the element at the top, replace `bottom: 0` by `top: 0`

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked  for me:

```
tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
        borderTopRightRadius: 40,
        position: 'relative',
        zIndex: 2,
        marginTop: -48
      }
  }
```