# React Native - View disappears when position is absolute on Android

Tags: react-native

Whenever I made the position style 'absolute' for this view, it disappears. I have no idea why it is happening.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <View
          style={styles.parentView}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.9}
            onPress={() => {}}>
            <View
              style={ [{position: 'absolute'}, styles.textView] }>
              <Text style={styles.textViewText}>
                Just Another Cat
              </Text>
            </View>
            <Image
              style={[{position: 'absolute'}, styles.imageView]}
              source={{ uri: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg' }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: { flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 },
  parentView: { alignSelf: 'center', flex: 0.5, left: 10, elevation: 3, alignItems: 'flex-start' },
  textView: { width: 250, height: 250, opacity: 1, borderRadius: 125, backgroundColor: '#aaa034' },
  textViewText: { textAlign: 'center', padding: 10, color: '#ffffff', fontSize: 18, top:0, right:0, bottom:0, left:0, textAlignVertical: 'center', position: 'absolute' },
  imageView: { width: 250, height: 250, borderRadius: 125, borderColor: '#000000', borderWidth: 0.2 }
});
```

When I remove the inline-style: (position: 'absolute') added alongside styles.textView and styles.imageView, they both will be visible again. But I want to make the position absolute for some reason, but then they just disappear. I don't know why. Can anyone explain this?

EDIT: It works in iOS. It's giving this bug on android. Snack URL: https://snack.expo.io/Hy_oRrvOM

Comment: You have to add some `left, right, top, bottom` properties, no? At least one. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541971/absolute-and-flexbox-in-react-native

Comment: Tried so, isn't working still.

Comment: I've put your code in a [snack here](https://snack.expo.io/Hy_oRrvOM). Is this the expected behavior? I'm not sure if I'm seeing the same thing as you

Comment: It's blank. It should show the image/option text like it does when they're not absolute. Do you see the image? Edit: just checked, it works in iOS but not on android. Run the code on iOS and you'll see the "cat" image but when you run it on android, it won't show you anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the width and height of the `TouchableOpacity` are zero! because the contents of that are absolute, so you need to set (left, right, top, bottom) for one of the children or set the width and the height for the `TouchableOpacity` itself

**Why it works in iOS?**
because in iOS `UIView` doesn't clip its children by default, so actually `TouchableOpacity`'s width and height are still zero but the children overflowed and you can see them,
 there is a flag for that ([Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds))

but in android `ViewGroup` always clips its children

**How to solve problems like this?**
there are some tools that you can debug UI at runtime, but I think the easiest way in react-native is set `backgroundColor` from the root view to the target view!

so for example in this case: first set `backgroundColor` for `mainView` then if it does show, set `backgroundColor` for `parentView` and then for `TouchableOpacity` and you can see it doesn't show `backgroundColor` of `TouchableOpacity` because the `width` and `height` of that are zero, in each step you can set `width` and `height` manually to ensure about the problem

Comment: Is there a way to set TouchableOpacity's width and height? I googled and found "likely" similar issue, the proposed solution is to add a parent with width and height: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1322

Answer (score 7):

Add `zIndex:100` to your attributes. Worked for me. Not exactly, you just have to put a high enough value for your zIndex param, to put it on top of others.

Comment: underrated comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved mine by giving parent component a flex:

```
position:'relative',
flex:1
```

Just dropping it soo it could be helpful to people.

Comment: Glad to know ! @BuddhikaJayawardhana

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced this problem and it seems like specifying minWidth and minHeight for the parent of 'absolute' positioned elements solves the problem.

EDIT: Actually specifying width and height also solves it.

Here is the updated [snack](https://snack.expo.io/Bk8o6KlSm). See line 11.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like z-index works from top to bottom.

Without setting the zIndex manually, your absolutely positioned component should be lower in order of appearance/line number in your code for it to layer over the content below it.

so

`<Underlay/>`

then

`<AbsolutelyPositioned/>`

and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment because of I don't have enough rep, However, additional to what Amir Khorsandi said, you can also use onLayout to see what value you are getting. This way you can see it in your remote console log, even the x and y of the said View. I hope it helps.

```
<View onLayout={(event) => {
                var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout; console.log(x, y, width, height)}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions I have tried but none worked for me. Here is my style of View.

```
modal_continue_button:{
            top:0,
            backgroundColor:greentext ,
            width:150, 
            height:40,
            borderTopLeftRadius:30,
            borderBottomLeftRadius:30,
            alignItems:"center",
            justifyContent:"center",
            position:"absolute",
            bottom:5,
            zIndex:100,
        },
```

Finally i have found a solution of this by adding the transform property to the style element. Now it is woring fine.

```
modal_continue_button:{
        top:0,
        backgroundColor:greentext ,
        width:150, 
        height:40,
        borderTopLeftRadius:30,
        borderBottomLeftRadius:30,
        alignItems:"center",
        justifyContent:"center",
        position:"absolute",
        bottom:5,
        zIndex:100,
        transform: [{ scale: 1.1 }]
    },
```

you can change the transform property to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

```
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Rooms Tab. {id}</Text>
            <View style={styles.fab}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <AntDesign name="plus" size={30} color="#ffffff" />
            </View>
        </View>
```

```
    container: {
        height: '100%',
    },
    fab: {
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        backgroundColor: colors.primary,
        borderRadius: 50,
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 1,
        right: 1,
        zIndex: 100
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `<view>` tag higher **zIndex**, so it will hide behind prev absolute elements, So try to add negative **zIndex: -1**

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete .... styles={{ ..... listView: styles.listView, }} />
<View style={styles.field}> .... </View>

field: { zIndex: -1 },
```

**Note**: Above `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` dropdown gets hide under below view element. So just  **zIndex: -1** will gives solution.**Try this solution for sure**