# How to extend tab screen under tab bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to extend the tab view (image) all the way to the top of the screen and have the tab bar overlay it? Tab bars' `backgroundColor` is `"transparent"`. Using `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` from [React Navigation v3](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/material-top-tab-navigator.html). There seems to have been something along the lines of `displayUnderTabBar` option in the earlier versions but I can't seem to find it in the documentation anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you do is create a custom component for the tabs and position it absolutely over the screens.

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyCustomComponent {...props} />}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Check out the example of a custom tabBar component [here](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Tab%20navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fmaterial-top-tab-custom-tab-bar.js).

In the above example, make the  positioned absolutely to top. Note that if you do this, however, you will need to change **TouchableOpacity** to **TouchableWithoutFeedback** because of the problem noted in this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051707/react-native-view-disappears-when-position-is-absolute-on-android).

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this, following styles need to be applied to the custom Tab Bar component that's passed in to the `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`:

```
style={{
    ...
    position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 1,
    width: '100%'
    ...
}}>
```